# Regular Expression for Conditional Substitution of Angle Brackets

Tags: regex, tags, markup, substitution, komodoedit

Is it possible to create a single regexp to replace < and > with their entity equivalents in Komodo Edit?

```
s/<|>/&lt;|&gt;/
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you may have to convert `&` to `&amp;` and so on.

If this is the case there's most likely a library or function in whichever language/platform you're using (e.g. in Java check out [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)). Indicate which language you're using and someone here will no doubt point you to something appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy in to do this in just about any language *without* using regex:

**PHP:**

```
$xml = str_replace(array('>', '<'), array('&gt;','&lt;'), $xml);
```

**Python:**

```
xml = xml.replace('>', '&gt;').replace('<','&lt;');
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language you are using. In Perl, you could do:

```
s/([<>])/$1 eq '<' ? '&lt;' : '&gt;'/ge
```

Other languages usually allow you to provide a match callback function that returns a replacement string. To wit: In C#, you can do this:

```
Regex.Replace("<", "([<>])", x => x.Value == "<" ? "&lt;" : "&gt;")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash-variable, something like:

```
my %data;
$data{"<"} = '&lt;';
$data{">"} = '&gt;';
s/(<|>)/$data{$1}/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I was looking for something I could use in [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit), so variables and conditional statements were not an option. Here is the best solution I found, which was based on a Sed tutorial at [IBM Developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-sed2.html):

```
s/<([^>]*)>([^<]*)<([^>]*)>/&lt;\1&gt;\2&lt;\3&gt;/
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Komodo Edit 5.x](http://downloads.activestate.com/Komodo/releases/archive/5.x/), use the [moreKomodo](http://community.activestate.com/xpi/morekomodo) extension to save the following find/replace [regex search](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/5.2/search.html#search_regex):

Find:

```
<([^>]*)>([^<]*)<([^>]*)>
```

Replace:

```
&lt;\1&gt;\2&lt;\3&gt;
```