# Is there a way to force XML to include closing tags when using toString() or toXMLString()?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, e4x

When I convert XML to a string it converts empty nodes to a singleton leaf. Is there a way to request that it use closing tags instead of singletons?

For example, here is pseudo ActionScript3:

```
var xml:XML = new XML("<XML><NODE/></XML>");

var output:String = xml.toXMLString();
```

trace(output);

```
<XML>
   <NODE/>
</XML>
```

What I want is:

```
<XML>
  <NODE></NODE>
</XML>
```

PS I'm using AS3 and Flash Player 12 which uses E4X.

**Back Story:**
I'm generating HTML page and then running it through an XML validator and I would like it to be valid and it has problems with things like `<link>` that in boiler plate they don't close the tag, no "/". There are other cases I have `div` that when exporting to XML string the XML class rewrites those as `<div/>` which breaks the HTML page. Sometimes, the nodes will be empty. If I put a space or value in the node it will change the layout of the page.

So basically, there are a few reasons where keeping empty nodes from being written as singletons would be beneficial.

Comment: what is your end goal/how would you use <link></link> ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza It's just an example. I updated the XML example.

Comment: Ok, let's pretend you've got that problem solved, how would use the solution ? Would you add something <NODE>HERE</NODE> for example ? I'm  not sure why you want to do what you're asking, that's all :)

Comment: OK :). I've added the story behind the question in the op.

Comment: Thank you, that's easier to understand :) Have you tried a zero-width space ? (`U+200B`) ?

Comment: I haven't heard of that. That might work.

Comment: maybe look at node.children and node.attributes and if neither has a length greater than zero, remove the node before you stringify it?!?

Comment: That would work for empty nodes but some nodes like the Link element don't have children but do have attributes. To be valid XML they need a close tag. There may also be cases where an empty need is desired for use at a later time.

Comment: @PaulSweatte thank you but this is not the same question. please remove the link at the top of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it is not possible. It may require an update from the Flash Player team.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `override` method to redefine `toXMLString`:

```
override public function toXMLString():String
{
    if (!localIndex)
    {
        return source.toXMLString();
    }
    else
    {
        var str:String = "";

        for (var i:int = 0; i < localIndex.length; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
                str += "\n"; // this matches how XML works

            str += localIndex[i].toXMLString();
        }

        return str.replace("<NODE/>","<NODE></NODE>");
    }
}
```

Or, a more generic version:

```
return str.replace(/<([^\/]+)\/>$/,"<$1></$1>")
```

**References**

- [XMLListCollection.as: toString and toXMLString](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flex-sdk/repo?p=flex-sdk.git;a=blob;f=frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.as#l355)
- [Regular Expression for Conditional Substitution of Angle Brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495425/1113772#17622695)
- [Overriding Methods](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcd.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f3c)
- [ActionScript toString() with Interfaces](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/11/actionscript-tostring-with-interfaces.html)

Comment: Interesting... I will have to validate this. This may be awesome. :)